# Flutter-Backendless User Login __ How to Validate User Credentials (Email and Password) to move from Login Page to Home Page

Tags: flutter, backendless

Newbie mobile developer here. I'm trying to implement User Logins with Backendless but I don't know whats the best way to do it, especially to avoid making too many API calls.

I know there are several malpractices (especially UX) here but I'm really just trying to get the logic right first.

In the following excerpt, I try making a log-in and when it's done give the user access to the app. If its not successful Id like the alert to be made. However, the app shows the alert independently of the credentials being correct. It's like the if starts executing before the login has been completed.

I'm not looking for a workaround, I'm a noob developer and honestly, don't know the best way to handle this. I would be very appreciative of help. Thanks, guys!

```
                              Backendless.userService.login(email, password).then((user) => boologin=true);
                              if (boologin==true) {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => Home(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              } else {
                                showBasicAlert(context,
                                    "Wrong username or password", "");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`boologin` is always `false` when it reaches to `if`. Because `login` is asynchronous and before `boologin = true` being set, code flow continues. Try to change it like here

```
await Backendless.userService.login(email, password);
```

Then to set `boologin = true`

Answer (score 0):

As Marat said, most of the calls to the Flutter Backendless SDK is asynchronous and
you can use the `await` keyword to wait for a Future to complete. Or you can perform actions in the response's body.

Here is the most convenient way to handle Backendless SDK calls:

```
void logIn(email, password) {
  Backendless.userService.login(email, password)
    .then((loggedInUser) {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Home(),
        ),
      );
    })
    .catchError((onError) {
      showBasicAlert(context, "Wrong username or password", "");
    });
}
```